# Unable to connect to google VM through mosh

Tags: google-compute-engine

[firewall config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ml8Jh.png)

I have opened the relevant port from firewall. I have setup the firewall config as in the image provided.

I have also opened port on the server with following command
`sudo ufw allow 60000:61000/udp` which is the relevant port used by mosh.
I have installed mosh on the server also and It connects through. Following the snapshot 
command `netstat -nulp`

[netstat -nulp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nJDR.png)

`mosh myserver@myip.com` still gives unable to receive any data on port 60001.

I dug deeper and found out that that opening all the ports on the firewall lets me connect to the google VM but config attached in the image should have been enough.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: configuration in the screen-shot you provided seems good for GCE firewall. Verify if UDP traffic to the chosen port number is working by running "nc -l -u 60001" on the server side, run "nc -u server-public-ip 60001" on the client side and confirm that anything you type on either end shows up in the other command’s stdout. Test the same for port 60002 as well. You can report your issue on [mosh github](https://github.com/mobile-shell/mosh/issues) as well.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got it working by bumping the [image: mosh firewall rule's] Priority to 2000 (so it is above the default-allow-internal udp rule)